# Seleccionar row y esos datos pasarlos a otro aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Por el momento solo tengo esta idea, cuando seleccione una columna, el `Id` se coloca  en un `Label` y al mismo tiempo se direcciona a la otra página, arrastrando el `Label3` (`id_cr`), y poniéndolo en otro `Label` en la nueva página (`Imp.aspx`) para llenar un formulario automáticamente, aquí la tabla que aparece en `Home.aspx`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí deben de aparecer la datos (`Imp.aspx`) obiamente se esta trayendo el dato del `Id` (de la tabla que esta en (`Home.aspx`), y en el  `PageLoad` (del `Imp.aspx.cs`) carga la tabla de la base de datos, aquí deben aparecer los datos:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow row = GridView2.SelectedRow;
        Label3.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
        Response.Redirect("Imp.aspx");

    }
```

¿Cómo relaciono el `id_cr` de página a página? ¿Qué recomendaciones usarían? Acepto opiniones con JavaScript, solamente que me familiarizo mas con C#, ¡Gracias!

Comment: Revisa está página de las ayudas de Microsoft, está en ingles https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Puedes llevar los datos que gustes en una variable de sessión, por ejemplo, suponiendo que el `id_cr` es de tipo `string`, inicialmente lo puedes asignar así:

```
Session["_id_cr"] = "id_cr";
```

Ahora, en donde desees recuperar el valor de `Session["_id_cr"]` es de la siguiente forma:

```
string id_cr = Session["_id_cr"].ToString();
```

Otra forma, es enviar los parámetros por medio del `Response.Redirect`. Para asignar la variable:

```
Response.Redirect("Imp.aspx?idcr=ValorDelIdCr");
```

Para recuperar el valor:

```
string id_cr = Request.QueryString["idcr"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Gracias!! pude resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

(Home.aspx)

```
        GridViewRow row = GridView2.SelectedRow;
        Label3.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
        String Valor = Label3.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Imp.aspx?valor=" + Valor);
```

(Imp.aspx)

```
        String Valor = Request.QueryString["Valor"];
        Label2.Text = Valor;
```